# How to calculate integral() at points where function returns constant

Tags: matlab, integral

I calculate this integral.

```
integral(@(x) f, xmin, xmax);
```

At `x = a, f(a) = constant` and the `integral(@(x) constant, xmin, xmax)` returns errors.

So,

1. How can I make this work at `x = a`.
2. How to detect if the function returns constant?

Comment: how you define the f(x) function?

Comment: it is a very long symbolic expression. I think the question is general, that's why I didn't mention the function. It is not working for all functions returning some constant value at some points. Like, if you write integral(@(z) 5, 0, 1) it will not return 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will solve the problem:

```
fun = @(x) 5;
integral(fun,0,1,'ArrayValued',true)
```

according to Mathworks:
Array-valued function flag, specified as the comma-separated pair consisting of 'ArrayValued' and either false, true, 0, or 1. Set this flag to true when you want to integrate over an array-valued function. The shape of fun(x) can be a vector, matrix, or N-D array.

Example: 'ArrayValued',true indicates that the integrand is an array-valued function.

Comment: This solved the problem. Thank you so much. I have to read the help more carefully. Spent much time on this.